# Create Generic Object from Interface?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

i'm programming for Win Phone 8 in VS 2013.

i have a Games Class with 2 Observable Collections:

```
public class Games
{
    public Games() { }

    public ObservableCollection<Game1> Games1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Game2> Games2 { get; set; }
}
```

Game 1 and Game 2 Class :

```
public class Game1: GameBase<PersonG1>
{
    public Game1(){}
    public string Game1Property{ get; set; }
}

public class Game2: GameBase<PersonG2>
{
    public Game2(){}
    public string Game2Property{ get; set; }
}
```

GameBaseClass:

```
public abstract class GameBase<TPerson> where TPerson : Person
{
    public string GameStatus { get; set; }
    public string GameDuration { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TPerson> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Person Classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class PersonG1: Person
{
    public string PersonG1Property{ get; set; }
}
public class PersonG2: Person
{
    public string Person2Property{ get; set; }
}
```

After Start the Phone App i will select a game, and i go to a xaml Page where DataContext = Game1 or Game2

But i Have an Page : MakePerson.xaml, this Page doesn't know about the DataContext or anything, i used it for add persons to each game, and would use the same MakePerson.xaml for all games, i go to Makeperson.xaml Page as follow:

```
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(GlobalResources.MakePersonPage + "?index=" + _gameIndex.ToString() + "&pId=-1&gametype=Game1", UriKind.Relative));
```

Where _gameIndex represents index for the Game in the ObservableCollection, pID represents personIndex in the ObservableCollection Persons, and gt represents gametype, arrived at the Makeperson.xaml Page i do:

```
private object currGame;
private Person currPerson;
DataContext = currentPerson;
_gameIndex = int.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["index"]);
_personIndex = int.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["pId"]);
_gameType = NavigationContext.QueryString["gametype"];
switch (_gameType)
        {
            case "Game1":
                {
                 currGame = Games.Games1[gameIndex];
                 currPerson = Games1[gameindex].Persons.ElementAt(personindex); 
                }
            case "Game2":
            currGame = Games.Games2[gameIndex]
            currPerson = Games2[gameindex].Persons.ElementAt(personindex); 
        }
```

How can i Change this structure, so i can work more comfortable in makePerson.xaml? I Think about Generic with Interface?

How i must change my classes, so i have always the same object, for example perhaps like this:

```
 switch (_gameType)
        {
            case "Game1":
                IGame currGame = Games.Game1s[_gameIndex];
                currentPerson = currGame.Persons.ElementAt(persondindex);
                break;
            case "Game2":
                IGame currGame = Games.Games2[_gameIndex];
                currentPerson = currGame.Persons.ElementAt(persondindex);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Or Other Solutions i can use?

Thanks . 
(And sorry the bad english)

Comment: make it more simple, it hard to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your games are already inheriting from GameBase, so you should be able to use normal polymorphism. So instead of your currGame being of type "object" it can be of type "GameBase".

```
GameBase currGame;
switch (_gameType)
    {
        case "Game1":
            currGame = Games.Game1s[_gameIndex];
            currentPerson = currGame.Persons.ElementAt(persondindex);
            break;
        case "Game2":
            currGame = Games.Games2[_gameIndex];
            currentPerson = currGame.Persons.ElementAt(persondindex);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Edit:
You don't want to cast to an interface, since it is redundant.
But you might be able to change your GameBase to:

```
public abstract class GameBase
{
    public string GameStatus { get; set; }
    public string GameDuration { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for answer, i have tried it first so, but then i had Ambiguos ObservableCollection Persons.. i don't know what my mind looks for generics and interfaces... the only i would is have a GameBase, then deriving GameA,GameB from Base, and each derived Game must have a PersonList with Specific person Type, and my goal is having an Object that represents me a Game with Person List, that can i cast, so i can call CurrGame.Persons (without knowing if CUrrGame is GameA or GameB. Can i Do this easier? WIthout generics and interfaces... or using interfaces only ? Thanks .